# How to list only author and revision numbers of paths added in svn repository?

Tags: shell, svn, unix, scripting

I want to list only revision numbers of added file in svn repository. I used svn log.
svn log -v -r {from}:{to} url |
grep -wo "r[0-9] *"
it lists all the revisions. but i want to list
revisions when the files have been added.
similarly i want to list only author who have
added files to the repository.
svn log -r {from} :{to} url--quiet | grep "^r" | awk '{print $3}'
its list me all the authors who made changes to
repo for date range. But I want to list only
authors who added files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have less number of files, you could go ever each file, request the log, and get only the first log entry for each file.
Then you know which author has added this file in which revision....

But this is only useful if you want to know this on still existing files.

Do you want a script sample for this ?

Comment: I have huge number of files.Is it possible through scripting.

Comment: Second method would be todo svn log complete and parse it... but i would recommed to use some higher then bash for example.

Comment: I can also recommend to use svn log -v --xml . With a multi line regular expression it should be possible to filter action="A".